# Flip a column of Data vertically Import range

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query

I'm importing the data from another sheet using the import range. How can I flip a column of data vertically in another Google Spreadsheet?

```
=sort(index(IMPORTRANGE("URL")
```

E.g. if the column is:

```
Cat
Dog
Tiger
Mouse
```

I want:

```
Mouse
Tiger
Dog
Cat
```

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour). Consider sharing a publicly editable [sample spreadsheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/269219) with realistic-looking data.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do that would probably be to import the data in a helper column, and then use `sort()` to show it in reverse order, like this:

`=sort(A2:A, row(A2:A) * (A2:A <> ""), false)`